# SSRS Tablix Dyanmic Column Groups on Parameter values with Page Breaks

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, parameters, grouping

I currently have a tablix that looks like this:

[image]

I also have three parameters:

[image]

When the user selects the report parameter, this tell the query what columns in expected value to show. So the columns pivoted are dynamic based on that parameter.
If the user selects multiple parameters for report, I'd like the report to page break based for each parameter they choose.

Example:

[image]

Here the user chose ILO, IP, and LogicDrive for the report parameters. These are all the columns that will show in expected value.
Instead off all them being grouped together, I'd like the to create individual column groups with a page break in between.

Is this possible?

### Update

I managed to get the column values grouped by the parameter:

[image]

I created a parent column group like this:

[image]

Now my issue is getting the page breaks in between each column grouping.
I read based on this Microsoft doc that it may not be possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-page-break-report-builder-and-ssrs

It says: Page breaks are ignored on column groups.

Is this still true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by page breaking after each column group, doesn't make sense to me? Even if it was possible do you mean you would end up with just a single column of data on each page? If so why bother with column groups at all. Yo probably need to post some sample data expected output. Just make up fake data if you have to as long as the structure is similar to your real data.

Comment: Each column groping contains multiple columns. In the end each page break would have static columns, and they dynamic column that belong within that column group.